# Can I get a live camera image inside my App in Firefox OS?

Tags: javascript, camera, getusermedia, firefox-os

So I am having a look into Firefox OS right now. One thing I would like to try is to manipulate the device camera's live feed using canvas et.al.

From what I can see in the blog posts (like **[this one](https://hacks.mozilla.org/category/firefox-os/as/complete/)**) and the code in the boilerplate app this is always done using a `MozActivity`, meaning that the user is leaving the application, takes a picture and passes this picture back to the application, where I could post-process it.

But for live manipulation I would need to have a live camera feed inside my App, just like you would do using `getUserMedia` when accessing a computer's webcam. `getUserMedia` doesn't seem to be supported in the Firefox OS simulator though.

Is there any workaround to this or some API that I am missing?

Comment: @Charles Open Web App is a term coined by Mozilla for Apps running on Firefox OS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Apps so maybe the tag might get relevant some time in the near future and even deserve a tag. For now I can live without it and would prefer an answer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer this with the response I got from the Mailing List (the answer is "not yet"):

> WebRTC will (hopefully) land in Firefox OS 1.2 (as reference, the
>   initial launch is on 1.0.1, closely followed but dependent on carriers
>   is 1.1). WebRTC is a of lot of low-level hardware dependencies, so it
>   might take longer.
>
> You can follow along on this meta bug and its dependencies:
>   https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=750011

Thanks for the answer, Mozilla, can't wait for 1.2!

Answer (score 0):

refer to thread [getUserMedia for Firefox OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813121/getusermedia-for-firefox-os)

WebRTC for audio is supported in Firefox OS 1.2.
But WebRTC for video (ex: live camera feed) is just landed in Firefox OS 1.4, which is still in development phase. So be patient, it will be available this year.