# getUserMedia for Firefox OS

Tags: html, mozilla, gecko, firefox-os, b2g

It was said that getUserMedia would [land on Firefox OS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106584/can-i-get-a-live-camera-image-inside-my-app-in-firefox-os). I have read the documentation and tried to look for it in the Google Groups, but I have not found anything related to it.

I have developed a web app that works on Firefox Nightly (so, it works in Gecko):
[image: getUserMedia seems to work properly.]

But when I try to use it in Firefox OS 1.4, I get a "Permission denied" error:
[image: Error get trying to access to the media device.]

I have tried to add the following permission to the manifest:

```
  "permissions":{
    "camera":{}
  }
```

But didn't solve the problem. Is there any other permission that I would need to add?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

getUserMedia support for the microphone landed in FxOS v1.2.  getUserMedia support for the camera just landed on trunk (v1.4) about a week ago.  The final piece to land was support for permission prompts : bug 853356 in bugzilla.mozilla.org (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=853356).  Prior to a week ago, you would have gotten a permission error.

Currently the camera always returns frames in landscape mode.  Bug 970183 (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=970183) tracks that problem, and we're actively working to land a fix for this ASAP.

Comment: A cool Mozilla have also noticed me that I need the "video-capture" and "audio-capture" permissions.

Answer (score 6):

you need add `video-capture` permissions in manifest.webapp in 1.4 for getUserMedia video, 
and `audio-capture` permissions in manifest.webapp in 1.2 for getUserMedia audio, ex:

```
  "permissions": {
    "audio-capture": {},
    "video-capture": {}
  }
```